# I have a feature that turns on every Wednesday and checks if there are any birthday people next week

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

it happens that the month ends in the middle of the week and I need him to check the dates of birth and at the beginning of the next month, but he just doesn't work and I can't figure out why

```
    async def find_bithday():
       today = datetime.today().date()
       start_day = today + timedelta(days=5)
       end_day = start_day + timedelta(days=7)
       print(start_day, end_day)
       async with session() as sess:
            bithday_all = await sess.execute(
                select(
                    Vip_Clients.full_name,
                    Vip_Clients.address,
                    Vip_Clients.phone,
                    Vip_Clients.birthday
                ).where(
                    extract('day', Vip_Clients.birthday) >= extract('day', start_day),
                    extract('day', Vip_Clients.birthday) < extract('day', end_day),
                    and_(
                        or_(
                            extract('month', Vip_Clients.birthday) == extract('month', start_day)
                        ),
                        or_(
                            extract('month', Vip_Clients.birthday) == extract('month', end_day)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            return bithday_all.all()
```

there are two people with a birthday at the end of this month and at the beginning of the next, I expected that it should give me both, but this function does not give anyone away

Comment: Let's say your `start_day` is 25th and `end_day` is 3rd of next month. There is no possible value of birthday that is both > 25 and < 3.

Comment: Exactly, can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have to do the `extract(...)`? Won't simple `start_day < Vip_Clients.birthday < end_day` work?

Comment: it doesn't work because there is still a year of birth, it spoils everything

Comment: besides this method, I do not know how to compare the month and date of birth

Comment: A bit more dirty, but `start_day.replace(year = 1) < Vip_Clients.birthday.replace(year = 1) < end_day.replace(year = 1)` should work.

Comment: Note: this will fail at the end of the year similiar to how your code failed at the end of each month.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the fact you didn't calculate correctly the end of the week, in your code for calculate this, you simply add 7 days at the current date, but this doesn't consider that the week could finish into another month. I modified the logic to correctly calculate the end of the week taking into account the peculiarities of the calendar. In addition, I added specific handling to correctly identify birth dates that fall at the end of the current month and the beginning of the next month. Therefore, you could try something like this:

```
async def find_birthday():
today = datetime.today().date()
end_of_week = today + timedelta(days=(6 - today.weekday()))

if today.month == 12:
    next_month = 1
    next_year = today.year + 1
else:
    next_month = today.month + 1
    next_year = today.year
end_of_next_month = today.replace(day=1, month=next_month, year=next_year) - timedelta(days=1)

async with session() as sess:
    birthday_all = await sess.execute(
        select(
            Vip_Clients.full_name,
            Vip_Clients.address,
            Vip_Clients.phone,
            Vip_Clients.birthday
        ).where(
            or_(
                and_(
                    extract('month', Vip_Clients.birthday) == today.month,
                    extract('day', Vip_Clients.birthday) >= today.day,
                    extract('day', Vip_Clients.birthday) <= end_of_week.day
                ),
                and_(
                    extract('month', Vip_Clients.birthday) == next_month,
                    extract('day', Vip_Clients.birthday) >= 1,
                    extract('day', Vip_Clients.birthday) <= end_of_next_month.day
                )
            )
        )
    )
    return birthday_all.all()
```

Tell me if it works, good day :3